# How can I implement clustering with PSO(Particle Swarm optimization) with a dataset in python?

Tags: python, cluster-computing, particle-swarm

I am try to implement pso in python with dataset
I tried the code given below. But I am unable to use pso for a dataset(Iris /Wine). Can anyone help me?I want to implement clustering using pso in python.
  I am try to implement pso in python with dataset
I tried the code given below. But I am unable to use pso for a dataset(Iris /Wine). Can anyone help me?I want to implement clustering using pso in python.

`Code (taken from google)
     from __future__ import division
     import random
     import math
x=int(input("enter the value of x =  "))
     # function we are attempting to optimize (minimize)
    def func1(x):
    total=0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        total+=x[i]**2
    return total
   class Particle:
    def __init__(self,x0):
        self.position_i=[]          # particle position
        self.velocity_i=[]          # particle velocity
        self.pos_best_i=[]          # best position individual
        self.err_best_i=-1          # best error individual
        self.err_i=-1               # error individual`

```
    for i in range(0,num_dimensions):
        self.velocity_i.append(random.uniform(-1,1))
        self.position_i.append(x0[i])

# evaluate current fitness
def evaluate(self,costFunc):
    self.err_i=costFunc(self.position_i)

    # check to see if the current position is an individual best
    if self.err_i<self.err_best_i or self.err_best_i==-1:
        self.pos_best_i=self.position_i.copy()
        self.err_best_i=self.err_i

# update new particle velocity
def update_velocity(self,pos_best_g):
    w=0.5       # constant inertia weight (how much to weigh the previous velocity)
    c1=1        # cognative constant
    c2=2        # social constant

    for i in range(0,num_dimensions):
        r1=random.random()
        r2=random.random()

        vel_cognitive=c1*r1*(self.pos_best_i[i]-self.position_i[i])
        vel_social=c2*r2*(pos_best_g[i]-self.position_i[i])
        self.velocity_i[i]=w*self.velocity_i[i]+vel_cognitive+vel_social

# update the particle position based off new velocity updates
def update_position(self,bounds):
    for i in range(0,num_dimensions):
        self.position_i[i]=self.position_i[i]+self.velocity_i[i]

        # adjust maximum position if necessary
        if self.position_i[i]>bounds[i][1]:
            self.position_i[i]=bounds[i][1]

        # adjust minimum position if neseccary
        if self.position_i[i]<bounds[i][0]:
            self.position_i[i]=bounds[i][0]

class PSO():
def __init__(self, costFunc, x0, bounds, num_particles, maxiter, verbose=False):
    global num_dimensions

    num_dimensions=len(x0)
    err_best_g=-1                   # best error for group
    pos_best_g=[]                   # best position for group

    # establish the swarm
    swarm=[]
    for i in range(0,num_particles):
        swarm.append(Particle(x0))

    # begin optimization loop
    i=0
    while i<maxiter:
        if verbose: print(f'iter: {i:>4d}, best solution: {err_best_g:10.6f}')
        # cycle through particles in swarm and evaluate fitness
        for j in range(0,num_particles):
            swarm[j].evaluate(costFunc)

            # determine if current particle is the best (globally)
            if swarm[j].err_i<err_best_g or err_best_g==-1:
                pos_best_g=list(swarm[j].position_i)
                err_best_g=float(swarm[j].err_i)

        # cycle through swarm and update velocities and position
        for j in range(0,num_particles):
            swarm[j].update_velocity(pos_best_g)
            swarm[j].update_position(bounds)
        i+=1

    # print final results
    print('\nFINAL SOLUTION:')
    print(f'   > {pos_best_g}')
    print(f'   > {err_best_g}\n')

 if __name__ == "__PSO__":
main()

initial=[5,5]               # initial starting location [x1,x2...]
bounds=[(-10,10),(-10,10)]  # input bounds [(x1_min,x1_max), 
(x2_min,x2_max)...]
PSO(func1, initial, bounds, num_particles=15, maxiter=50, verbose=True)
```